# Hive: timestamp interval

Tags: sql, hive

how to get time interval for `timestamp` like `2015-09-11 10:04:31` and `2015-09-11 10:04:55` ?

Comment: What result are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unix_timestamp`:

```
SELECT (unix_timestamp('2015-09-11 10:04:55') - unix_timestamp('2015-09-11 10:04:31'))
```

This would return the difference in `seconds`. If you want to convert it into minutes, divide by 60.